# Content invisible using Itext in Java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, itext, invisible

I'm using the `iText` library with Java and I have an issue, let me explain:
I have a Word file converted into a PDF and i want to add a table at the end of the document, this works perfectly except when the Word file hasn’t active the feature "No Color" at the tab "Page Layout", the table adds it as "invisible".

I've already tried to change the property  Font from the Chunk object that created the content, but it does not work, the table continues showing as "invisible".
How I can solve this

The following code is the one that I use to create the table:

```
Font font = new Font(1,fontSize, Font.BOLD);
font.setColor(0,0,0);

Chunk name =  new Chunk(v_emp.getNombre(),font);
Chunk tipo =  new Chunk(v_emp.getDireccion(),font);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(tipo);
paragraph.add(new Chunk("\n"));
paragraph.add(name);


PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
cell1.setPadding(2);
table.addCell(cell1);
```

Comment: Please provide some code you wrote

Comment: You're not telling us how you are adding the table: maybe you're adding it under an opaque rectangle, maybe you're adding it outside the visible area of the page,... You need to post an example (PDF as well as code) that helps people to reproduce your problem. Otherwise, you'll get downvotes and votes to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the table in PDF with your mouse and see if the table is there and still it is invisible.

If it is there, go to the file menu and do print as pdf.